# Using Geolocation in a HTML5 Web Worker

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, web-worker

I want to use a HTML5 web worker to report longitude and latitude to a restful server at regular intervals - even when the tab is not in focus. My problem is that the way that I would normally access the HTML5 [geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) function is not available in the web worker.

What I have tried is sending the geolocation object, from my main file to the web worker. However, that didn't work and I got the following error:

> Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker':
>   An object could not be cloned.

Next I tried importing a JavaScript library which provides geolocation services called [Geolocator](https://github.com/onury/geolocator). But then I found that I do not have access to the library in the worker (I think because the worker doesn't have access to the DOM).

So, in an attempt to combat this, I added the source of this JavaScript library directly into the worker file but this didn't work because I don't have access to `window` which is used repeated throughout the source of [Geolocator](https://github.com/onury/geolocator).

Is what I am trying to do possible? Is there any alternatives which I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `navigator` object in the main thread [contains a `geolocation` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation), which is how you access all geolocation functionality.

Workers contain a [different `navigator` object, known as `WorkerNavigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerNavigator) which only contains a subset of the properties of the `navigator` in the main thread.

Because the `WorkerNavigator` lacks a `Geolocation` object and the `Geolocation` object can't be serialized *into* a worker, it appears you can't use `Geolocation` inside of a web worker. Instead, you'll have to do your reporting from the main thread.

Comment: Okay, thats disappointing. Do you know of anything similar to web workers that will run even when a tab isn't in focus?

Comment: @Haych I'm not but perhaps you could have a timer running in the web worker then alert the main thread to perform the REST call? I'm not sure if that would work, I haven't tried it.

Comment: There is an ongoing discussion on [w3c repo](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745) that started in September 2015 about possible implementation of Geolocation in ServiceWorkers

Answer (score 0):

There is a working example of your proposal that can be found at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206149/expected-ratio-of-serviceworker-instances-to-geolocation-updates) question. It currently only works in background on Firefox (for the wrong reasons) and is unlikey to get implemented until we have substantial regime change at W3C/IETF.

But like you, there are ***many*** such requirements out there in the real world and I believe my proposal meets most if not all of them.