# Is it reliable to unregister service worker on window.unload event?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am using something like this to unregister my service worker:

```
window.addEventListener("unload", () =>{
     registration.unregister().then(function(successs) {
         if(successs){
             console.log("Unregister succesfull!");
         }
         else {
             console.log("unregister unsuccessfull!!");
         }
     });
});
```

Since the unregister function returns a promise, it seems that the unregister process is asnyc. So is it reliable to do this unregistration on the unload event?

I have tested on Chrome and it works, but can't find anything in the spec or anywhere that can validate whether what I am doing will always work.

**MORE INFO**

I know that it seems weird unregistering the service worker on document unload. But I am not using the service worker for caching or notification or other PWA stuff. I am using to serve a dummy HTML page that I generate at runtime. So I just open an iframe with some dummy src and start intercepting all the requests from that iframe from the service worker. I want this service worker to be unregistered after the user closes the tab.

Comment: It would probably work, but... could you elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve? Using a service worker that only stays registered until you navigate away from the current page sounds less than optimal.

Comment: There is a github issue [here](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/731), but I don't think it a good idea to manage a service worker like this.

Comment: I dont want to save anything in IndexedDB using the service worker. I just want the service worker to be cleaned up after the user closes the tab. See the more info section of my question

Answer (score 0):

There is a working example that can be found via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206149/expected-ratio-of-serviceworker-instances-to-geolocation-updates) Look at the RegisterServiceWorker.js file that is called from TravelManager.html.

I don't get any console output after the call so assume the promise is not resolved? Either way what does it do? IMHO the registration of a Service Worker (intrinsically for ***many*** clients/pages) should not be bound to one page.

The manifest registration/declaration functionality seems to be there?

What do you want the unregister to do?

Comment: I just want the service worker to be cleaned up as I am not using it for caching and stuff but instead for serving a dummy page that I generate at runtime

Comment: I like that idea too, Like closing files, releasing memory and so on. The thing I struggle with is the scoping of ServiceWorkers and their 1:M relationship with clients. That is, who is Client Page A to shutdown a SW that Client B maybe using/relying on because he is in scope. I wonder if it signals a new version of the SW will be installed and the current on quiesces?

Comment: You can assume that there is a new service worker per tab. So other tabs will not be affected by the unregister.

Comment: @tapananand where did you come up with that incorrect assumption? Are you familiar with "scope" and the Clients object? Emphasis on the "S"

Comment: I use a random scope each time I register a service worker. So each tab gets a new service woker instance. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Have you got a link to your example? You can find an example of sending messages to ALL SW clients in echo.js here: - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Rmd3Rn8_hDNW1zSWRoXzBTclU Although I now believe the UA should have client-specific geolocation filtering and supply a Client.id withe the TravelEvent

Comment: What is the answer to my question? Is it not reliable to unregister on the unload event?

Comment: The spec says it is. My "working" example unloads don't give errors but the page does not survive to log console output.

Comment: Can you cite where does it say that in the spec? I didn't find anywhere in the spec talking about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149906/discussion-between-tapananand-and-mcmurphy).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't tie it to an event on one page, otherwise having multiple tabs open of the same page will be hard to handle. Personally I'd have the service worker query for clients with setInterval and if the number of clients drops to zero, unregister itself (with self.registration.unregister()).

Edit: it turns out the above doesn't work due to web workers getting eventually killed. I've ended up using the above strategy but instead of setInterval, every time the site is closed it sends a message to the service worker which then checks how many clients it still has.